# How to add Fragments in ViewPager to TabLayout from a web service?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm trying to add tabs to my `TabLayout-ViewPager-Fragment` based application dynamically.The `TabLayout` uses a custom view with an `ImageView` on top of a `TextView`.

What I want now is to add tabs according to the number of `JSONObjects` in my `JSONArray` created from a PHP/MySQL web service. I tried the method below in my `PagerAdapter` but it throws:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment TstFrag{df80bc8 #0 id=0x7f080157 android:switcher:2131231063:0}: was android:switcher:2131231063:0 now android:switcher:2131231063:1`.

The method is as in my Adapter below

```
public class FrgAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public FrgAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public FrgAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragmentList, List<String> mFragmentTitleList) {
    super(fm);
    this.mFragmentList = mFragmentList;
    this.mFragmentTitleList = mFragmentTitleList;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public void insertFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, Fragment fragment, CircularImageView imageView, TextView textView) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject sectionObj = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);

        JSONArray sectionsArray = sectionObj.getJSONArray("section");

        for (int j = 0; j < sectionsArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) sectionsArray.get(j);
            Picasso.get().load(obj.getString("imag")).into(imageView);
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(obj.getString("name"));
            textView.setText(obj.getString("name"));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return null;
}}
```

Here is where the method is called in my activity to add the fragments:

```
private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, View view) {
    adapter = new FrgAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    /*adapter.addFragment(new MleFrag(), "Men");
    adapter.addFragment(new FmlFrag(), "Women");
    adapter.addFragment(new ChdFrag(), "Children");
    adapter.addFragment(new AceFrag(), "Accessories");
    */
    String url = "https://44091ee6.ngrok.io/Glam/men.json";
    AndroidNetworking.get(url)
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        adapter.insertFromJSONObject(response, new TstFrag(), view.findViewById(R.id.circularImageView), view.findViewById(R.id.text_header));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), anError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and here is my `Fragment`. In my mind I want to reuse this one `Fragment` for each of the times I will be requiring one.

```
public class TstFrag extends Fragment {

public TstFrag() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cht, container, false);
}}
```

Comment: where is defined the `imageView` variable? Also, please post the code of TstFrag. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry I was trying it out without the imageview but let me update the code

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531732/1283715)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
adapter.insertFromJSONObject(response, view.findViewById(R.id.circularImageView), view.findViewById(R.id.text_header));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and

```
public void insertFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, CircularImageView imageView, TextView textView) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject sectionObj = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);

        JSONArray sectionsArray = sectionObj.getJSONArray("section");

        for (int j = 0; j < sectionsArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) sectionsArray.get(j);

            Picasso.get().load(obj.getString("imag")).into(imageView);
            mFragmentList.add(new TstFrag());
            textView.setText(obj.getString("name"));
            //mFragmentTitleList.add(obj.getString("name"));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea here is to create a new instance of `TstFrag` for each entry of the `FrgAdapter`.

Comment: I took long to reply because I had already figured this out.Its working but now another issue is I get the tabs but they are empty.i.e the image and text are not loaded.I will accept this answer however for anyone who might have te same issue

Comment: BTW, You shall load image **in/after** fragment `onCreateView`

Comment: Image is loaded I think simultaneously with fragment oncreateview because I call the method to get the images at the same time when Im attaching viewpager to adapter.By the way till now I havent got it to work.The images and text are not showing despite the number of fragments crreated matching the length of my JSONArray

Comment: If you want just to cache images while paring `JSON` to be. ready when user slide pager then use `Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fetch(callback)`

Comment: @Thekamble Check my [answer update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702866/1283715) on how to pass data to fragment and handle rendering UI there on fragment `onCreateView`

Comment: IM trying it now and what it seems to do is load the image and text into the fragment but what I want is for them to be loaded into the tablayout as the custom view.Let me try fix it though.If i get stuck ill ping  again

Answer (score 1):

Consider **NOT** to add fragments to `viewPager` manually but just implement `getItem` && `instantiateItem` methods on viewPager adapter. Then viewPager will control the `instantiation` of new `TstFrag` or just **reuse created** one. **Check this [answer for complete adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531732/1283715).**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int pos) {
    return TstFrag.getInstance(dataList.get(pos));
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

**Update**

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable{
  private String name;
  private String image;
  // GETTER && SETTER 
}
```

**Replace**

> `private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();`

**With**

```
 private List<DataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**insertFromJSONObject**

```
    dataList.clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < sectionsArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) sectionsArray.get(j);
        final DataModel model = new DataModel();
        model.setName(obj.getString("name"));
        model.setImage(obj.getString("imag"));
        // Picasso.get().load(obj.getString("imag")).into(imageView);
        // No need to load image here just fetch for cache if you want.
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).fetch();
        // mFragmentList.add(fragment); // no need handle adding fragment here as mentioned above.
        dataList.add(dataModel);
        // textView.setText(obj.getString("name")); // It's not good to update UI here but update there with fragment on create called mention below.
        // notifyDataSetChanged(); DON'T call this inside the loop but after finish your stuff.
    }
    // Just notify here...
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**TstFrag**

```
public class TstFrag extends Fragment {
 private DataModel model;
public TstFrag() {

}

public static TstFrag getInstance(DataModel model){
  TstFrag fragment = new TstFrag();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putSerializable("mData", model);
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  return fragment;
} 

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    model = (DataModel)getArguments().getSerializable("mData");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cht, container, false);
    // findViewById() for imageView and nameTextView 
     Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(imageView);
     nameTextView.setText(model.getName());

}}
```

Comment: I already got it working using @Lino's answer but an upvote because this method seems solid.Actually I saw such a suggestion earlier but wanted to proceed with the other method.Thanks for the fast response though